# Update en laravel

Tags: base-de-datos, crud, update

Soy nuevo utilizando laravel y quisiera saber como pasar la siguiente consulta a laravel

```
UPDATE users
INNER JOIN tm_employee ON users.id = tm_employee.UserId 
SET users.groupId = '' 
WHERE tm_employee.id = ''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira si te sirve así:

```
 DB::table('users')
   ->join('employee', 'users.id', '=', 'employee.UserId')
   ->where('employee.id','')
   ->update([ 'employee' => '' ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Si estas trabajando cada una de tus tablas por medio de los modelos de
>   Laravel, deberías hacer lo siguiente

**En el controlador**

Aquí puedes invocar al modelo User de este modo

```
use App\User;
```

Después de eso, tu consulta debería verse así

```
$data = User::join('employee', 'users.id', '=', 'employee.UserId')
   ->where('employee.id','')
   ->update([ 'employee' => '' ]);
```

Finalmente para que esto funcione, te debes dirigir al modelo `User` y declarar lo siguiente

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

**LO QUE HCIE FUE**

1. lo anterior se hace para que con esto no intente actualizar tu columna `updated_at` es decir esa la ignore
2. Las columnas y sus valores que se usarán en la actualización se mandan dentro del método `update` bajo el formato de *clave=>valor*